# Increment alphanumeric code based on values in another Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and have been stuck while working on an automation in Excel using VBA.

**The Automation Problem**

The idea is to automate the generation of an alpha-numeric code in my Excel file, based on values that can be found in **another Excel file**.

For simplicity sake, we'll call these two files the **Original file** (my file) and the **Target file** (where values can be found). Both have exactly the same format i.e. the same column headings.

In order to tackle this problem, I've split it into 4 parts:

1) Identify the directory that contains the Target files.

I have found some code online that can help me with this -

```
Sub getdirectory() 

Dim xRow As Long 
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$ 

InitialFoldr$ = "G:\" '<<< Begins searching from here

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" 
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from" 
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$ 
    .Show 
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then 
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7) 
        Do While xFname$ <> "" 
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$ 
            xRow = xRow + 1 
            xFname$ = Dir 
        Loop 
    End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

2) Select the Target file that is most recent (based on its date)

[image]

In this case (as shown in the photo), the file right at the bottom is the most recent, and should be selected.

3) Once selected this Target file, we select the code in column 1 of this Target file with the highest value, based on some conditions-

Condition 1: In the Original file, if 'Account Type'= Site and Segment='Operations', then the code in the Target file starting with 'OSM' that has the **highest value**: i.e. OSM_SITE_0006805 is **returned to the Original file**, and the code is incremented by 1. Then subsequent codes respecting the same condition are incremented by 1.

Condition 2: In the Original file, if 'Account Type'= Site and Segment='Sales', then the code in the Target file starting with 'OSE' that has the **highest value**: i.e. OSE_SITE_0006105 is **returned to the Original file**, and the code in incremented by 1. Then subsequent codes respecting the same condition are incremented by 1.

The process continues till all rows have been complete in the Original file.

**Final Result**

[image]

Any input I can get from this community will be very helpful and will prove to be a good learning for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community site is based on a question/answer system. Meaning people come here with a **specific** question to code they have written themselves. Your question is very broad and more likely a question for a forum based site where discussion and teaching are possible. If you have a specific question to your code, you are welcome to show your code and ask a more specific question.